# LinkedIn 410 error code while authentication and Graph APIs

Tags: linkedin-api, http-status-code-410

We have an app with LinkedIn and implemented server side authentication for generating tokens. Since 22nd march 2018, all our requests to LinkedIn API endpoints are failing. We could not either sing up new users or could share to users who are already connected.

For example, when we try to use the share api endpoint "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares", we are getting below response.

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "This resource is no longer available under v1 APIs",
  "requestId": "75VVVZNEH1",
  "status": 410,
  "timestamp": 1521743007330
}
```

Reaching the forum to confirm if this is a generic LinkedIn issue for all or we are only facing this also to get help from LinkedIn experts to get out of this situation.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question for LinkedIn, not StackOverflow.

Comment: Dear @GaneshSittampalam , Can you please provide the link where we can post to LinkedIn

Comment: There's a link in the tag wiki, but I don't think they care about providing support.

Comment: LinkedIn official support page [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/support) refers stackoverflow as collaboration platform for issues. Hence posted in this forum. So this can't be voted for closure here.

Comment: StackOverflow determine the rules for this site, not LinkedIn.

Comment: We just started seeing this problem today as well. No idea what changed. 

And IMO it's totally appropriate to ask API questions here for LinkedIn, especially given the fact that they direct questions here. Plenty of projects work this way.

Comment: The problem we faced was resolved. The moment we approved for LinkedIn partnership program, all our existing APIs broken with 410 error. We had to migrate our API endpoints to resume our services back. Hope this helps